# Error deploying war with spring mvc 5.0.7.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, war, weblogic12c

I am trying to create war with below but while deploying in wls12c getting error

`applicationContext.xml` as below :

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.listeners.config, com.xyz.listeners.controller"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="PropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                 <value>WEB-INF/classes/myapp.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <import resource="spring-beans/server-spring-beans.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Spring Version : 5.0.7.RELEASE

Getting below error while deploying the web app:

```
ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1610540534203> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "spring-dispatcher" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "mywar".
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 24 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid  nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException  systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd  lineNumber: 24  columnNumber: 20  cos-all-limited.1.2: An ''all'' model group must appear in a particle with '{'min occurs'}'='{'max occurs'}'=1, and that particle must be part of a pair which constitutes the '{'content type'}' of a complex type definition.
```

Comment: This is the import on applicationContext.xml <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

Comment: Don't add additional code in comments as those are totally unreadable. Instead edit the question and add it there. Looking at what you posted you have the header twice in your XML, basically making your XML invalid.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks . I did corrected the question. In actual xml header present once only.

Comment: What is line 24? The error isn't in this file (although there is an error) as it complains about something that isn't present in this file.

Comment: its line 24 of http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd

Comment: Which you aren't even importing as it isn't part of your schema declaration.